# android pass ArrayList<self_Obj> by Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I had create a class named ChannelObj that contains values like this

```
public class ChannelObj {
public String enable;
public String id;
public String name;
public String ptz;
public ChannelObj(Node n){
     this.enable =  n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("enabled").getNodeValue();
     this.id = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
     this.name = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
     this.ptz = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("ptz").getNodeValue();
}
}
```

and this Class can create Obj that contains what data I need;

after that,I have an ArrayList named allChannel contains all ChannelObj i have

like this

```
        for(int i = 0;i<num_of_channel;i++)
    {
        allChannel.add(new ChannelObj(n1.item(i)));
    }
```

i've checked the data in allChannel is correct

but i want pass this ArrayList to next Activity

i've tried ways like

```
            Intent i = new Intent(this,ChannelListActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelableArrayListExtra("dd", ArrayList<ChannelObj> allChannels);
        i.putExtra(String name,b);
        startActivity(i);
```

but didn't work and still wrong

what i suppose to do?

thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you expand upon what "didn't work" means and what "still wrong" means. For example, provide what you expect as result and contrast with your actual result. Is there an error, crash, etc?

Comment: I've know what's the problem already...

cause the obj in my arrayList is my self-define obj,but still thanks for your help!

Comment: only objects of type parcelable can be sent through intent...
but whats your problm???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clas must implement `Parcelable` check it out here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the answer given by Benoir is to have your `ChannelObj` class implement the [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) interface. You're only using simple data types, so all the (de)serializing will be automa(g)(t)ically done underwater.

If your class implements Serializable, then you can add it to a Bundle as follows:

```
bundle.putSerializable("CHANNELOBJ_LIST", mChannelObjList);
```

Note that you may need to cast to an `ArrayList<ChannelObj>` (or some other concrete implementation of `List<T>`) as the `List<T>` interface does not implement Serializable.

Retrieving the list of objects in the next activity is similarly easy:

```
List<ChannelObj> mChannelObjList = (ArrayList<ChannelObj>) bundle.getSerializable("CHANNELOBJ_LIST");
```